# Dimension in xna

Tags: java, xna, dimension

In java there is a varible type called `Dimension` where you can store a width and a height ex: `Dimension dimension = new Dimension(900,600)`. I need something like this in xna, I'm aware of `Vector2` and `Point` but those are for storing coordinates not a dimension. Can someone tell me something similar in xna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While tom502's answer is technically correct, it requires you to reference `System.Drawing.dll`, which is only available on the Windows platform.

If you want to stick to straight XNA, you should either just use `Vector2` or implement your own `Dimension` structure.  You're correct in that a `Vector2` is supposed to represent a spatial coordinate, rather than the size of an object, but XNA itself uses it to represent size as well--for example, when measuring strings.  There's not a whole lot of point in having two structures that are basically identical except for name.

Answer (score 1):

There is the `Size` structure in C# - it houses a height and width

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size.aspx